# Tomcat server failes to start

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have searched a lot and tried many solutions but I can't get the server to run. I am trying to make a login app using `jsp` and `servlets`. First I created the `index.jsp` file which looks like this:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginform" action="login" method="post">
<p>User Name: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I selected the `Run on Server` option it worked just fine and displayed the form. After that I created a new servlet named `Login`:

```
package servlets;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Login
 */
@WebServlet("/Login")
public class Login extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Login() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("We are in Post method servlet");
    String username = "user";
    String password = "rood";

    String un = request.getParameter(username);
    String pw = request.getParameter(password);

    String msg = " ";

    if (un.equals(username) && pw.equals(password)) {
        msg = "Hello " + un + " Your login is sucessful";
    } else {
        msg = "Hello " + un + "Your login failed";
    }

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<font size='6' color=red>" + msg + "</font>");
    }

}
```

and I have configured the `web.xml` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>LoginExample</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now when I click again `Run on server` I get an error `Server Tomcat v7.0 Server at localhost failed to start.`

I will post all the output I get in the console. I appologise for this post being so long but I said to post everything maybe it will be more easier for someone to figure it out what is wrong. So:

```
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:27 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:LoginExample' did not find a matching property.
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Nov 3 2014 08:39:16 UTC
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.57.0
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8.1
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.3
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JAVA_HOME:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_31-b13
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\W7\Desktop\drept\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\W7\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\W7\Desktop\drept\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\W7\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.57
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\W7\Desktop\drept\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\W7\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.57\endorsed
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_31\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_31/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Qt\4.8.4\bin;C:\Users\W7\Documents\mingw\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0\bin;C:\strawberry\c\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\bin;C:\Dwimperl\perl\site\bin;C:\Dwimperl\c\bin;C:\Program Files\Rational\common;;C:\Users\W7\Desktop\eclipse-web\eclipse;;.
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1466 ms
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:28 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [142] milliseconds.
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LoginExample]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LoginExample]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> Login in servlet mapping
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3300)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.addServletMapping(StandardContext.java:3275)
    at org.apache.catalina.deploy.WebXml.configureContext(WebXml.java:1438)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1357)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:889)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5380)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 6 more

Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more

Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Feb 01, 2015 11:24:29 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
```

I will be really greatful if someone could help me solve my problem, so that I can move on.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Since you have added @WebServlet("/Login") ,
so no need to map url pattern again in web.xml 


remove this tags  from web.xml and run again or remove @WebServlet("/Login")  and keep tags in web.xml and change action in form as action="/Login".
 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>servlets.Login</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I get the same error as I posted in the comment above

Comment: @dres remove Webservlet and put <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern> instead of capital Login and put slash also

Comment: action="login" change it to action="/login"

Comment: Now the server sarts but I get another error. Could you please check the edited question and have a look inside the doPost method and tell me why it's not displaying the message.I get `The requested resource is not available.`

Answer (score 2):

That is the root cause of the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid <url-pattern> Login in servlet mapping
```

Think you have to change:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Login</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Login</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I changed the `.xml` file but now I get `The servlets named [Login] and [servlets.Login] are both mapped to the url-pattern [/Login] which is not permitted`

Comment: @dres just change the name , `<url-pattern>/doLogin</url-pattern>` and use it in your form's `action` sorry to interfere @Jens

Answer (score 0):

You are using web.xml version 3.0 

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" **version="3.0"**>

Its not mandatory to make ur servlets entry in web.xml. Just try to remove it from web.xml. and put this line before class defination starts.
@WebServlet("/Login")

now try to hit url:

localhost:port on which ur server is running (Default is 8080)/project_name/Login